# 71 hotkeys have been received in the last X ms

Tags: autohotkey, global-hotkey

I have a script that assign <kbd>F1</kbd> for a global task:

```
f1::Run D:\Download
```

A program needs to use that key, so I put this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe inkscape.exe
F1::send {f1}
return
```

However when I press it, this error hits:

[image]

If yes, nothing happens. If no, the script exits.

Do you know what happens?

Comment: The problem that your hotkey keeps triggering itself over and over a again in a loop the [`$`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) modifier will fix it, but I don't really know what you're trying to do. Could you try to explain better what you're trying to do? Why do you have two hotkeys for F1 (only one will work at once by default) and what's this *global task* run command?

Comment: The F1 key is pretty useless, so I want to assign it to a global hotkey. However, in one program that key is useful, so I want to keep the default function of F1 in that specific program. That is, if that program is open and in the foreground, the script will not run. Is that better?

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah that's no problem. I'll write an answer right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your hotkey keeps triggering itself over and over a again in a loop. The [`$`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) modifier will fix it. That way the hotkey wont get triggered when the source of the key press is a `Send` command.

However, you don't actually need this at all.
You should use the [`#IfWinNotActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.

```
#IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe inkscape.exe
F1::Run, D:\Download
#IfWinNotActive
```

Alternatively, you could just not create a context sensitive hotkey, and use the [`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) modifier. That way the hotkey will always retain its normal functionality when you press it.
`~F1::Run, D:\Download`